# Date format in django queryset extra() in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
Sales(models.Model):
    # ... ommitted fields...
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

I'm filtering sales data with the total amount of sales in a month using this query

```
Sales.objects.all()
    .extra(select={'month': 'MONTHNAME(date)'})
    .values('month')
    .annotate(total=SUM('amount'))
    .values('month', 'total')
```

The output something like this:

```
[
    {
        "total": 186.0,
        "month": "July"
    },
    {
        "total": 278.0,
        "month": "August"
    }
]
```

but what i want is to format the month name in 3 letters only to display like this: `'Jul'` and `'Aug'` and `.extra(select={'month': 'DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b')'})` doesn't work.

**Django: v1.10+**

**Database: MySQL**

Comment: what does this return .extra(select={'month': 'MONTH(date, '%b')'})

Comment: it returns `unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 58` sir

Comment: try monthname inplace of month

Comment: when you look carefully to my question that is my original approach

Comment: no you used date_format, i am asking monthname in that place, .extra(select={'month': 'MONTHNAME(date, '%b')'})

Comment: tried it but still got this one `unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 62`

Comment: Note that using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) is discouraged. You should be able to use annotate with a [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression instead.

Comment: @Alasdair you may be right, had to try it

Comment: Try with `select={'month': 'MONTH(date)'}` as described in http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php .. As I'm not able to test the output. Commented out

Comment: @NagarajTantri hi tried it already but month() does returns only the number of month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked `.extra(select={'month': "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b')"})` and seems like you need an extra `%` before `b` which will get you the month in 3 letter. There was a similar issue in Django [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16889#comment:2)

For today's date, `.extra(select={'month': "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%%b')"})` prints **Jul**

**And Better** if you want to avoid using `extra` and create a **database agnostic** solution, then you can use [TruncMonth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.TruncMonth)

```
sales_data = Sales.objects
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date', tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')))

print sales_data.month.strftime('%b')  # Prints Jul
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange, but %% is required in the formatting string. Additionally, you may have to specify the table (tasks) in cases of ambiguous column names on joins.

```
tasks = tasks.extra(
  select={
    'lastModified':
      "DATE_FORMAT(%s.lastModified, '%s')" % (
        Task._meta.db_table,
        '%%m-%%d-%%Y',
      ),
    'dateRequested': "DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested, '%%m-%%d-%%Y')",
    'dateCompleted': "DATE_FORMAT(dateCompleted, '%%m-%%d-%%Y')",
  },
)
```